# 5.3.3-7+squeeze18 and Zend Framework 2 not working

Tags: php, zend-framework2, webserver, composer-php

Issue is that Zend FW2 requirements is 5.3.3 as my php interpreter version, but while it is trying to be installed by composer generates an error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0 requires php >=5.3.23 -> no matching package found.
>       - zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0 requires php >=5.3.23 -> no matching package found.
>       - Installation request for zendframework/zendframework 2.3.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zendframework[2.3.0].
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
>   https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion
>   for more details.
>
> Read http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for
>   further common problems.

What is the solution, except php version update(not suitable, because on this server i have another project which will not run after update).

**Thank you for your time and help!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution you have is to use an older Version of Zend Framework

```
php composer.phar require zendframework/zendframework 2.2.*
```

This will leave you at `2.2.5` or `2.2.6` not too sure about that. For all newer Versions you **will need** at least `PHP 5.3.23`. Sticking to 5.3.3 just because Ubuntu ships with 5.3.3 is a bad, bad, bad thing! Don't ever make your Web-Server dependent on the version of your Operating System. That's just absurd.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sam's answer and your question. It is possible to run more then 1 apache instance at a given time [see here](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RunningMultipleApacheInstances). When creating a new config file you'll need to the assign the desired .php version. It could look something like this:

```
#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
</Directory>
    <Directory "c:/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
ScriptAlias /php/ "c:/php/"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
Action application/x-httpd-php "/php/php-cgi.exe"
```

This particular problem is better be asked in https://serverfault.com/ since this is hardly a zf2 related question.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that you'll need to install a additional php version.  While **5.3.2** may be the minimum requirement I usually like working with 5.4 or later due to the array feature upgrade and traits.